# Access to server without writing port after address

Tags: c, http, port

I'm creating my custom http server in C. sockaddr_in looks like this:

```
my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
my_addr.sin_port = htons(8080);
my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htol(INADDR_ANY);
```

And my question is how I can send my request without writing port after address.
For example 192.168.1.100 instead of 192.168.1.100:8080 or mydomain.loc instead of mydomain.loc:8080

Comment: Do you mean like from a web browser? `http://192.168.1.100:8080`? The default port for http is 80. AFAIK, if you want to use a different port it has to be specified in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

> how I can send my [HTTP] request without writing port after address[?]

You cannot communicate with a TCP endpoint without designating a specific port.  Various kinds of services have conventional (default) ports, however, and oftentimes client software will use a service's conventional port if the user does not explicitly specify one.

The conventional port for the HTTP protocol is 80.  If your server runs on that port, then it is likely that HTTP user agents such as web browsers will not require you to specify that port; instead they will silently insert it for you.  You will need root / administrator privilege on the server machine to run the server software on port 80, or on any other port less than 1024.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your custom server with any web browser then you must have to specify the listening port of your custom server because every browser will consider a server listening on port 80 on the address (URL) you provided.

> how I can send my [HTTP] request without writing port after address[?]

And if you want to provide only the host IP address and using the 8080 port as default listening port of your server, you can make a simple custom client. Pass the host URL i.e. `192.168.1.100` to that client. In the body of client, connect the socket to `192.168.1.100` and `8080` address.  Client will send query to your custom server and will save the reply in `.html` file. You can then open this file with browser.